# restrict private apt repository with rssh - why does apt-get try /bin/sh?

Tags: shell, ssh, apt, repository

I am trying to set up a private repository via ssh. My `sources.list.d/` contains the entry

```
deb ssh://user@host:/repo ./
```

user is a certificate only account on host. `apt-get update` works fine.

However, I would like to restrict the access to downloading the repository, i.e. disable shell access. If I set the user shell to rssh, allowing only scp and sftp, the update breaks.

From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
user user attempted to execute forbidden commands
command: /bin/sh
```

Why does apt need shell access on the repository machine, and is there a way to avoid this?

I noticed there is an github repository for apt-transport-sftp which I might have a look at, but I'd rather stick to more common packages for user convenience.

Comment: Did you read *and understood* [the basic description of `rssh`](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/)? It’s a very restrictive shell, whereas `apt-get` needs the full system access to actually install or update anything.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi apt-get does not install or update *anything* on the repository machine. As far as I can see, it only has to access the file structure and download the packages. It even knows which files to look for (Packages or Packages.gz)

Answer (score 3):

### What is APT doing remotely

I have set up a test account, and logged every command `apt` executed
on the remote server by using a simple script as a replacement for the
repo owner's shell.  Apparently, `apt` is spawning a remote shell in
order to find the full path to well-known files::

```
2015-09-14: Executing 'sh -c /bin/sh'; input and output follows:
find /tmp/repo/./InRelease -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./Release.gpg -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./Release -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./Packages.bz2 -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./it_CH.bz2 -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./it.bz2 -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./en.bz2 -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

find /tmp/repo/./Packages.xz -follow -printf '%s\n' 2> /dev/null || echo

...
```

Therefore, I think you cannot restrict actions of the repo user via
`rssh`, as: (1) the commands to be executed are being passed to the
remote shell via STDIN (as opposed to SSH's remote exec feature), and
(2) commands are shell pipelines.

### Workarounds?

If you still want to restrict actions performed by the repo user
remotely, I see two ways forward:

- Set the repo user's shell to
  [rbash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html)
  instead, and provide a customized `$PATH` setting with only the
  commands that need to be run.  (Be sure to set `$PATH` and unset
  other shell variables from a startup file that *cannot* be written
  from the repo user.)  This still leaves the possibility to anyone
  having the access credentials to read any file in the system.
- Create a chroot jail with just the repo files and any command needed
  by APT, and set the repo user's shell to a script or program that
  performs `chroot /jail "$@"` instead.

### Logging `apt-get update` actions

Here's the script I used to log actions executed remotely::

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$(date -I): executing 'sh $@'; input and output follows" >> /tmp/sh.log
tee -a /tmp/sh.log | /bin/sh "$@" | tee -a /tmp/sh.log
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the analysis. Yes, I think  chroot is the way to go. I guess `find`ing the files instead of just assuming a path is somewhat more reliable with a seldom used apt protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You have no way to avoid this.

With default ssh method, `apt` needs to login to remote server, call `/bin/sh` to get the shell access and does some work with some GNU utilities like `find`, `dd`.

The [apt source code](https://alioth.debian.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=apt/apt.git;a=blob;f=methods/rsh.cc;h=44aa7084d02b3592eedbf1bbb2ef2109031bc546;hb=HEAD#l157) confirmed it:

```
 157       Args[i++] = "/bin/sh";
 158       Args[i] = 0;
 159       execvp(Args[0],(char **)Args);
 160       exit(100);
```

(It's surprising that `apt` still use `find` with `-follow` option, which marked deprecated)